# C# Dictionary with list as base

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a custom dictionary that uses a List as a base (will be used in XML deserialization). I can't figure out how to create it as the key can't be put on string it seems.

The dictionary would have the key property of the TestObject as the Key and as Value it would have the TestObject itself.

```
public class TestObject
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

}

public class CustomDictionary<string, TestObject> : List<TestObject>
{

}

public class Methods
{
    public void TestMethod(List<TestObject> list)
    {
        var testObject = new TestObject()
        {
            Key = "TEST",
            Property1 = "ABC",
            Property2 = 123,
        };

        CustomDictionary<string, TestObject> dictionary = new CustomDictionary<string, TestObject>(list);

        var test;
        dictionary.TryGetValue(testObject.Key, out test);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile, and you have no reason to create a custom `Dictionary` for this. Just use `Dictionary<string, TestObject>`

Comment: Generic dictionary can also do that

Comment: But the result from the xml serialization is a list of those TestObjects and I would like to have a Dictionary with a property of that TestObject as a Key.

Comment: @Mirzoda Why not deserialize into a normal list and then create a dictionary from that with whatever as key? LINQ's `ToDictionary` comes handy for that.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your last comment, what you want to do is something like this:

```
public class Methods
{
    public void TestMethod(List<TestObject> list)
    {
        Dictionary<string, TestObject> data = list.ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
    }
}
```

This uses LINQ's `ToDictionary` method, although a simple foreach loop would suffice.

Comment: list.ToDictionary(x => x.Key) is enough, i think

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Yes, I forgot about that overload. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the help!